# Linear map $K : C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ is given as $(Kf)(x) = \int^1_0 k(x,y)f(y)\,dy$. Find $\|K\|$.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

I'm solving the following problem.

> Let $(C[0,1], \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ be the space of real continuous functions equipped with the uniform norm. Let $k : [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a nonzero continuous function. Define $K : C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ as:
>
> $$(Kf)(x) = \int^1_0 k(x,y)f(y)\,dy, \quad f \in C[0,1]$$
>
> Show that $K$ is bounded and compute $\|K\|$.

This question has beed asked several times before: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/550657/144766) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1879501/144766). However, no answer actually constructs the sequence of functions which is needed to prove that $\|K\|\ge \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \int^1_0 |k(x,y)|\,dy$, nor at least precisely and elementary specifies the density argument which was used. So I have written a complete proof with an explicit construction of the approximating functions. Could you verify it?

$$\|Kf\|_\infty = \sup_{x\in [0,1]}\left|\int^1_0 k(x,y)f(y)\,dy\right| \le \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \int^1_0 |k(x,y)||f(y)|\,dy \\
\le \left(\sup_{x\in [0,1]} \int^1_0 |k(x,y)|\,dy\right)\|f\|_\infty$$

Thus, $K$ is bounded and $\|K\|\le \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \int^1_0 |k(x,y)|\,dy$.

Let show that $\|K\|= \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \int^1_0 |k(x,y)|\,dy$.

Since $x \mapsto \int^1_0 |k(x,y)|\,dy$ is continuous, there exists $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $$\int^1_0 |k(x_0,y)|\,dy= \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \int^1_0 |k(x,y)|\,dy$$

Now we $\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}$could take $f(y) = \sgn k(x_0,y)$ and notice that $\|f\|_\infty = 1$ and

$$Kf = \int^1_0 |k(x_0,y)|\,dy$$

so we are done. However, $f$ is not necessarily continuous so let's try to approximate it with continuous functions.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and $M = \max_{(x,y)\in [0,1]^2} |k(x,y)|$.

Since $k(x_0, \cdot)$ is continuous, $k(x_0, \cdot)^{-1}(\langle 0, +\infty\rangle)$ is an open set so it can be written as a countable disjoint union of intervals:

$$k(x_0, \cdot)^{-1}\big(\langle 0, +\infty\rangle\big) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \langle a_n, b_n\rangle$$

Similarly:

$$k(x_0, \cdot)^{-1}\big(\langle -\infty, 0\rangle\big) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \langle c_n, d_n\rangle$$

Now define $$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\langle a_n+\min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}, \frac{b_n-a_n}{2}\right\}, b_n-\min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}, \frac{b_n-a_n}{2}\right\}\right\rangle \\
\cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left\langle c_n+\min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}, \frac{d_n-c_n}{2}\right\}, d_n-\min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}, \frac{d_n-c_n}{2}\right\}\right\rangle\\
\cup k(x_0, \cdot)^{-1}({0})$$

and define $f_\varepsilon \in C[0,1]$ to be equal to $\sgn k(x_0, \cdot)$ on $A$, and to an affine function on $[0,1]\setminus A$ connecting $\pm 1$ with $0$ so that $f_\varepsilon$ is continuous.

Now we have:

$$\begin{align}(Kf_\varepsilon)(x_0) &= \int_{[0,1]} k(x_0, y)f_\varepsilon(y)\,dy\\
&= \int_{A} \underbrace{k(x_0, y)f_\varepsilon(y)}_{=|k(x_0, y)|}\,dy + \underbrace{\int_{A^c} k(x_0, y)f_\varepsilon(y)\,dy}_{\geq 0}\\
&\geq \int_{A} |k(x_0, y)|\,dy\\
&= \int_{[0,1]} |k(x_0, y)|\,dy - \int_{A^c} |k(x_0, y)|\,dy\\
&\geq \int_{[0,1]} |k(x_0, y)|\,dy - M\lambda(A^c)\\
&\geq \int_{[0,1]} |k(x_0, y)|\,dy - \varepsilon\\
\end{align}$$

since

$$\lambda(A^c) = \lambda\left(
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty
\left[a_n,
a_n+\min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}, \frac{b_n-a_n}{2}\right\}
\right]
\cup
\left[b_n-\min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}, \frac{b_n-a_n}{2}\right\}, b_n
\right]
\right)\\
+\lambda\left(
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty
\left[a_n,
c_n+\min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}, \frac{d_n-c_n}{2}\right\}
\right]
\cup
\left[d_n-\min\left\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}, \frac{d_n-c_n}{2}\right\}, d_n
\right]
\right)\\
\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda\left(\left[a_n, a_n+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}\right]\right) + \lambda\left(\left[b_n-\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}, b_n\right]\right) + \lambda\left(\left[c_n, c_n+\frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}\right]\right) + \lambda\left(\left[d_n- \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+3}M}, d_n\right]\right)\\
=\frac{\varepsilon}{M}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{\varepsilon}{M}$$

Thus:

$$\|K\| \geq \frac{\|Kf_\varepsilon\|_\infty}{\|f_\varepsilon\|_\infty} \ge |(Kf)(x_0)| = \int_{[0,1]} |k(x_0, y)|\,dy - \varepsilon \xrightarrow{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{[0,1]} |k(x_0, y)|\,dy$$

So, $\|K\| = \int_{[0,1]} |k(x_0, y)|\,dy$ follows.

The situation would be similar (only easier) if $k(x_0, \cdot)$ had only finitely many points where it changes sign.

Comment: Why is $\int_{A^c} k(x_0, y)f_\varepsilon(y)\,dy\ge 0?$

Comment: @ChilangoIncomprendido $f_\varepsilon$ has the same sign as $k(x_0, \cdot)$ on the entire $[0,1]$. On $A^c$ it just ascends linearly from $0$ to $1$ and then descends from $1$ to $0$ if $k(x_0, \cdot) > 0$ on that interval. Similarly, if $k(x_0, \cdot) < 0$ then it descends from $0$ to $-1$ and then again ascends from $-1$ to $0$.

Comment: got it thanks. Nice proof.