# Norm of a functional on $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Calculate the norm of the functional
$$
\phi (f) = \displaystyle\int^1_0 f(t) a(t) dt, \hspace{1cm} a \in C[0,1],
$$
on $C[0,1]$

I would like to know if my proof is correct. I consider
$$
\begin{align*}
|\phi (f)| \le \max_{f\in C[0,1]} \left|\displaystyle\int^1_0 f(t) a(t) dt\right|& \\ \le \max_{f\in C[0,1]} \displaystyle\int^1_0 \left| f(t)| |a(t) \right|dt \\ \le \left| |a| \right|_{\infty} \max_{f\in C[0,1]} \displaystyle\int^1_0 \left| f(t)\right| dt \\ = \left| |a| \right|_{\infty} \left| |f| \right|_{\infty}
\end{align*}
$$
Then, $\left| |\phi| \right|_{op} \le \left| |a| \right|_{\infty}$.

For equality, suppose $\epsilon > 0$, there are $[a,b] \subset [0,1]$ such that $\left| |a| \right|_{\infty} - \epsilon < |a(t)|$ for $a<t<b$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left| |\phi| \right|_{op}\ge \frac{\left| |\phi (\chi_{[a,b]})| \right|_{\infty}}{\left||\chi_{ [a,b]}|\right|_{\infty}} = \frac{1}{(b-a)} \max_{f\in C[0,1]}\displaystyle\int^1_0 \left| \chi_{[a,b]}(t)| |a(t) \right|dt &\\ = \frac{1}{(b-a)} \max_{f\in C[0,1]}\displaystyle\int^b_a \left| a(t) \right|dt > \frac{\left| |a| \right|_{\infty} - \epsilon}{(b-a)}(b-a)
\end{aligned}
$$
Finally $\left| |\phi| \right|_{op} \ge \left| |a| \right|_{\infty}$.

I appreciate the comments and corrections

Comment: In the first part of the proof you should remove $\max_{f \in C[0,1]}$ since $f$ is fixed. For the second part of the proof, the idea is great but the issue is that $\chi_{[a,b]}$ is not a continuous function so you have to approximate it by continuous functions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but could you give me a hint about the approximation, I understand something like a succession of functions, right?

Comment: Also note that $\Vert\chi_{[a,b]}\Vert_\infty\ne(b-a)$. In fact, this equality holds for a different norm than $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$. Consider this as a hint that what you are trying to prove is actually not correct, but that you should consider a different quantity instead.

Comment: Actually Martin is right, it should be $\|\phi\| = \int_0^1 |a(t)|\,dt$ and the proof is not trivial, see my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3913016/144766

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, it's easy to see that
$$
||\phi||_{op} \le \int^1_0 |a(t)|dt
$$
and for equality you can consider the sign function $f = sgn(a)$, then for $a(t) \neq 0$
$$
||\phi||_{op} \ge |\phi(f)|= \left|\int^1_0 sign(a) \cdot a(t)dt\right|
$$
but the product, $sign(a) \cdot a(t) = |a(t)|$. Finally
$$
||\phi||_{op} \ge \int^1_0 |a(t)|dt
$$
For the case $a(t)=0$, equality is trivial

Comment: This is not correct because $sgn(a)$ is not continuous.