# Norm of an integral functional

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, operator-theory

> Let $k\in C[0,1]$ and let $T$ be the functional on $C[0,1]$ (equipped with sup norm) given by $f\mapsto \int_0^1 kf$. Show that $\Vert T\Vert = \Vert k\Vert_1$.

**My attempt:** The inequality $\Vert T\Vert \le \Vert k\Vert_1$ is obvious. Indeed, $\Vert Tf\Vert \le \Vert f\Vert_{\infty} \int_0^1 |k|=\Vert k\Vert_1 \Vert f\Vert_{\infty}$.

On the other hand, for $f=k$, we have $$Tf=\int_0^1 k^2=\Vert k\Vert_2^2 \ge \Vert k\Vert_1^2\ge \Vert k \Vert_1$$ by Hölder's inequality. It follows that $\Vert T\Vert = \Vert k\Vert_1$.

> Is my solution correct?

PS: This question was actually answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3921358/266110) but there $f=sgn(k)$ which is not a continuous function, so I think the solution there is incorrect.

Comment: How about convolute $\operatorname{sgn}(k)$ with a family of bump functions to get a sequence that approximates $\operatorname{sgn}(k)$?

Comment: @JackyChong I don't know what are bump functions. What do you mean by convolute? Is my solution incorrect?

Comment: I thought the question, if any, was if the other solution was incorrect? Not if yours was correct??

Comment: @Paul No, I added the bit about the other question to avoid mine being marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I think $sgn(k)$ is continuous in $[0, 1]$ but not in $[-1, 1]$ say.

Comment: @Guest So why should $\|k\|^2_1 \ge \|k\|_1$? What if $\|k\|_1 = \tfrac12$?

Comment: @Paul That's not true, $sgn(k)(x)=1$ if $k(x)>0$ and $-1$ if $k(x)<0$. How can this be continuous?

Comment: @JackyChong Oops, you're right. Can you suggest a choice of $f$? I don't know anything about convolution and bump functions.

Comment: You have taken real analysis right?

Comment: Oops sorry, reading in a rush, thought k was x without thinking.

Comment: Can you please specify the domain, i.e. what functions $f$ do we consider (with what norm)? What is the definition of $\|T\|$? And how do you establish $\|T\|\le\|k\|_1$?

Comment: @Matija Sure, done.

Comment: @JackyChong Yes, maybe I'm just unfamiliar with the terms but not the actual functions?

Comment: Thanks! For your proof, it seems that you would need $\|Tf\|\ge\|k\|_\infty\|k\|_1$, right? Also, I think that you would need $\|k\|_1\ge 1$ for $\|k\|_1^2\ge\|k\|_1$.

Comment: @Matija Yes, JackyChong already pointed that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, we resolve the problem with the other solution by approximating $\mathrm{sgn}\circ k$ with continuous functions.

For $k\equiv 0$ we have $Tf=0$, hence $|Tf|=0=\|k\|_1$ and $\|T\|=0=\|k\|_1$, so let  $k$ be non-trivial.
For $\alpha>0$ let $f_\alpha(x)=1$ if $\alpha k(x)>1$, $f_\alpha(x)=-1$ if $\alpha k(x)<-1$ and $f_\alpha(x)=\alpha k(x)$ otherwise, then $f_\alpha$ is continuous. Notice that $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}f_\alpha=\mathrm{sgn}\circ k$.
Let $\mathcal X_\alpha=f_\alpha^{-1}(\{-1,0,1\})=\{x:f_\alpha(x)=\mathrm{sgn}(k(x))\}$ and notice that $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}\mathcal X_\alpha=[0,1]$.
Let $\alpha$ be sufficiently large such that $\|k\|_\infty(1-|\mathcal X_\alpha|)<\|k\|_1$, so in particular $\|f_\alpha\|_\infty=1$, where $|\mathcal X|=\int_{\mathcal X}$ is the area of $\mathcal X$.
Then we have $Tf_\alpha=\int_{\mathcal X_\alpha}|k|+\int_{[0,1]\setminus\mathcal X_\alpha}f_\alpha k\ge \int_{\mathcal X_\alpha}|k|\ge\|k\|_1-\|k\|_\infty(1-|\mathcal X_\alpha|)$. This gives $|Tf_\alpha|=Tf_\alpha\ge\|k\|_1-\|k\|_\infty(1-|\mathcal X_\alpha|)=(\|k\|_1-\|k\|_\infty(1-|\mathcal X_\alpha|))\|f_\alpha\|_\infty$. Hence, we have $\|T\|\ge\|k\|_1-\|k\|_\infty(1-|\mathcal X_\alpha|)$ for all $\alpha$, yielding $\|T\|\ge\|k\|_1$.

Comment: Here $\circ$ is composition or product?

Comment: Composition, it's equivalent to $\mathrm{sgn}(k)$ in the question.

Comment: I see. By the way, Once you get, $Tf_{\alpha} \ge \int_{X_{\alpha}} |k|$, can't you directly say that the latter is greater than $\int_{0}^1 |k|= \Vert k\Vert_1$?

Comment: Since we have $\mathcal X_\alpha\subseteq[0,1]$, we get $\int_{\mathcal X_\alpha}|k|\le\int_0^1|k|$. That's the wrong way round, right?

Comment: Oops, that's right! Thanks!